# Angular cannot scroll top in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular

I have the following form in my Angular project (I added jquery import to the ts file):

```
<style>
    body .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
        overflow-y:scroll; /* I made the scrollbar of modal visible */
    }
</style>

<div id="createForm" class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="ui-g form-group p-justify-between">
        <!-- other stuff -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use the following approach that I had used in my previous projects without any problem. I tried to trigger this method via a button but it does not make any sense:

```
scrollTop() {
    //when I use this it works but scroll the body behind the popup instead of popup
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 'slow');

    //this does not work
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#createForm').offset().top }, 'slow');
}
```

Is there anything that I should do for Angular?

Comment: Does anybody else has experience regarding to this issue???